# How can I determine which browser tab a request is coming from?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, postman

I set up a proxy (using Postman) that Chrome is now routing all requests through.

I see a bunch of requests being made to a site I don't recognize, and it repeats every few seconds. I have about 50 Chrome tabs open, so I'm wondering, is there a quick way I can determine which tab this request is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a quick way I can determine which tab this request is coming from?

After a quick Google search, a Chrome extension called [Web Sniffer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-sniffer/ndfgffclcpdbgghfgkmooklaendohaef) may be one solution to your problem. It lists requests made in real-time and has a column that has a link to the given tab that made a particular request:

*ex. Active Tab Links*

[image: Web Sniffer - Google Chrome - Tab Links - Screenshot]

That is, when you click the underlined `Tab` number (e.g. `457`), you will be taken to the open tab that generated the request.

As minor caveats, closed tabs don't have this option (i.e. there is no underline) and reopening a closed tab will (apparently) generate a different tab number.

Comment: The link is broken.